Finding PEAP/802.1x username in Windows
I'm trying to find just the username for accounts that have authenticated to our 802.1X network. We sometimes come across devices that were improperly set up and are missing identifying markers, so reporting on the username that has authenticated to the Wi-Fi network could be helpful in determining the device owner, or at least who touched the device last.
Because it's not a PSK, I can't use netsh wlan show profile name="SSID".
Similarly, there is no username data in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\%GUID%\%GUID%.xml
I can find MSMUserData in HKEY_USERS\%SID%\Software\Microsoft\Wlansvc\UserData\Profiles\%GUID%, but I'm not interested in decrypting it and uncovering passwords at all.
Is there any way to get just the username that has connected to our network, from the device itself? We'd be reporting on this remotely, likely through PowerShell.

This is resolved by decrypting MSMUserData, which I've learned does not unencrypt the password — that would require the additional step of running the program in the user context of the user that owns the key.
First, I search through C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\*\* for %GUID%.xml profiles that match the SSID for the network I'm looking for usernames for:
$targetSSID="mySSID"

$savedProfiles=$(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\*\*")
$matchingSSIDs=@()

foreach ($profile in $savedProfiles){
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content $profile
    $profileName = $xml.WLANProfile.name
    if ($profileName -eq $targetSSID){
        $matchingSSIDs += $profile | Select-Object basename
    }
}

if ($matchingSSIDs.Length -eq 0){
    Write-Output "Matching SSID not found. Exiting..."
    Return
}

Then I load each user's HKCU to search for the GUID that matched with our SSID:
$userObjects = $((Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\") | Where-Object {$(Split-Path $_ -Leaf) -Like "S-1-5-21-*"})

foreach ($userObject in $userObjects) {
    $loopUserSID = $(Split-Path $userObject -Leaf)
    $loopUserName = $(Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$loopUserSID" -Name ProfileImagePath | Split-Path -Leaf)
    $unloadAfter=$false
    if (Test-Path registry::HKU\$loopUserSID){
        $targetHive = $loopUserSID
    }
    else {
        reg load HKU\$loopUserName C:\Users\$loopUserName\ntuser.dat
        $targetHive = $loopUserName
        $unloadAfter=$true
    }

    foreach ($GUID in $matchingSSIDs){
        try {
            $installations = @(Get-ItemProperty -Path registry::HKU\$targetHive\Software\Microsoft\Wlansvc\UserData\Profiles\$($GUID.BaseName) -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object MSMUserData)
        }
        catch {
            Write-Output "Profile not found for $($loopUserName)"
        }
    }

    if ($unloadAfter){
        Write-Output "Unloading $loopUserName registry"
        if ($installations -ne $null){
            $installations.Handle.close()
        }
        [gc]::collect()
        reg unload HKU\$loopUserName
    }
}

Now with the MSMUserData that matches the GUID for our SSID, we can decrypt the first layer as long as the process has SYSTEM privileges.
Add-Type -assembly System.Security

foreach ($MSM in $installations){
    $bytes=$MSM.MSMUserData

    #this decrypts $bytes into ASCII
    $bytes2=[Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect( $bytes, $null, [Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::LocalMachine );

    $bytes2 = $($bytes2 -join ' ')

    #username begins after " 4 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 "
    $bytes2 = ($bytes2 -split " 4 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 ")[1]

    #username ends after first null bytes
    $bytes2 = ($bytes2 -split " 0 0 0 0")[0]

    $bytes2 = ($bytes2 -split " ")

    #convert ASCII to characters
    $username = [char[]][int[]]($bytes2) -join ''

    Write-Output $username
}

A big "thank you" to ash47 for https://github.com/ash47/EnterpriseWifiPasswordRecover/tree/master , which solved this.
